# waypoint counting element broken, no idea how to fix it

Tags: javascript, html, css, counter

I understand HTML and CSS code, but I am not a coder. I have aelements on a site that I need to fix...my site is www.subseasystems.com. The elements are circular- and show a "count up" to a dollar figure (ROI). there are three of them on the site.

The numbers are missing. I have no idea where those numbers live, but I assume it is in javascript, which I don't  know. Since they are missing, i can't even find and replace with new numbers...

Can anyone help me find the code that I need to fix, and maybe tell me how to fix it?

thank you so much
Terrie C

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: Unfortunately StackOverflow is not a great place to ask this kind of question. What you need is someone to assist you on the project? Or if you have a specific code question, paste what you've tried already.